# Font size too big when I place labels on a canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a canvas in WPF, contained within a viewbox to constrain it to a square aspect ratio:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <!-- make it square!-->
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" DataContextChanged="canvas_DataContextChanged" Width="300" Height="300"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Now when I place labels within that canvas in code, I find that the font size is huge, and even if I set it smaller, it doesn't shrink. Heck, if I shrink the viewbox itself, the text just gets cut off and becomes invisible! Here's the code where I place the labels (as well as some "sector view" controls which display the actual contents of the sectors in my game):

```
var w = canvas.ActualWidth / StarSystem.Diameter;
var h = canvas.ActualHeight / StarSystem.Diameter;

// TODO - place background

foreach (var sector in StarSystem.Sectors)
            {
                // place sector view
                var sectorView = new SectorView { Sector = sector, Width = w, Height = h };
                canvas.Children.Add(sectorView);
                Canvas.SetLeft(sectorView, (sector.X + StarSystem.Radius) * w);
                Canvas.SetTop(sectorView, (sector.Y + StarSystem.Radius) * h);
                Canvas.SetZIndex(sectorView, 0);

                // place label
                if (sector.SpaceObjects.Any())
                {
                    var label = new Label { Content = sector.LargestSpaceObject.Name, VerticalAlignment= VerticalAlignment.Bottom, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, Height=12, FontSize=10};
                    canvas.Children.Add(label);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(label, (sector.X + StarSystem.Radius) * w - label.ActualWidth / 2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(label, (sector.Y + StarSystem.Radius) * h);
                    Canvas.SetZIndex(label, 1);
                }
            }
```

As it stands, the labels are invisible (I assume because the text is getting cut off), but if I remove the font size and height properties, then the letters are as big as the sector views themselves, which is way too big - I only have something like a 15x15 grid on the entire screen; I want the text to overflow maybe one or two sectors over at most, along the very bottom of the sectors, not cover up entire swaths of space! ;)

Comment: I don't think the Viewbox does what you think it does. Remove it.

Comment: That said, I suggest you delete all this code and use proper XAML and DataBinding, as opposed to creating UI elements in code, which is considered a bad practice in WPF.

Comment: How am I supposed to "use proper XAML and DataBinding" when the whole structure of the UI depends entirely on the data itself? The number of sectors across the star system, whether or not a label is needed (if there's an object in a sector, it needs a label) - all of that is data driven. Is it really possible to design a UI that binds to data that isn't perfectly structured and aligned?

Comment: `Is it really possible to design a UI that binds to data that isn't perfectly structured and aligned?` - Yes. That's what a ViewModel is for. And all you're describing can be achieved with a WPF ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're specifying the Height explicitly. A Label control with a `FontSize` of 10 needs additional pixels for the actual line spacing and it will also usually have a default 5-pixel margin on both top and bottom which all together will result in a control that's around 23 pixels high. You're giving your labels a `VerticalAlignment` of `VerticalAlignment.Bottom` (which pushes the text itself to the bottom) and then explicitly setting the Height to 12 which is just enough to chop off the bottom entirely. The solution here is to not explicitly specify the height, but if for some reason you have to then give it an alignment of `VerticalAlignment.Top`, make the height large enough to accommadate everything and remove the label padding.

But HighCore is absolutely correct, creating your controls in code-behind like this is a horrible misuse of WPF.

UPDATE:

WPF is the perfect tool for this. As HighCore says, the idea is to do everything in the view model, that way you can indeed place breakpoints etc and track exactly what's going on. Here's an example which implement something similar to what I think you're trying to do...

I don't have your data structures so I'll start by creating a couple myself. I'm going to cut corners here and put all the data in the view model, in a real-world MVVM you would keep data in your models and then use view models to expose that data but let's keep things simple:

```
public class StarSystem : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Sector> _Sectors;
    public ObservableCollection<Sector> Sectors
    {
        get { return this._Sectors; }
        set { this._Sectors = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _Diameter;
    public double Diameter
    {
        get { return this._Diameter; }
        set { this._Diameter = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }


}

public class Sector : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._Name; }
        set { this._Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _X;
    public double X
    {
        get { return this._X;}
        set { this._X = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _Y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return this._Y;}
        set { this._Y = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _Size;
    public double Size
    {
        get { return this._Size; }
        set { this._Size = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Now in my main window I'll create a star system and set that as my DataContext:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new StarSystem
        {
            Diameter = 300,
            Sectors = new ObservableCollection<Sector>{
                new Sector{Name="Sector 1", X=50, Y=50, Size=110},
                new Sector{Name="Sector 2", X=160, Y=190, Size=90},
                new Sector{Name="Sector 3", X=225, Y=70, Size=70},
            }
        };
    }
```

Nothing terribly new or clever here, it's just the raw data for the objects you want to display including position and size etc. Here's the XAML to draw it:

```
<Viewbox Margin="20">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sectors}" Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}" Background="CornflowerBlue">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="AliceBlue"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Size}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Size}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Note that I've kept the Viewbox there, I'm assuming you want the whole scene to scale as the window is resized so we'll keep it in. There are a few things going on here:

1. We're rendering a list of objects (i.e. Sector), so we use an `ItemsControl`.
2. We bind that control's width and height to the StarSystem's Diameter, so you're now controlling the scaling of the whole scene in your view model very easily and without manipulating UI objects directly.
3. We're going to draw the sectors on a canvas, so we're wrapping one of those in an `ItemsPanelTemplate` and setting it as the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`.
4. We specify `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` with a `DataTemplate` containing the controls we want to use to render each sector.
5. We need to specify each sector's position and size. A common mistake is to do it in the `DataTemplate` but ItemControls actually wrap the `DataTemplate` in a `ContentPresenter`, so we need to set that instead. We do that by providing a style in the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`.

Result:

[image: Sectors]

That took me roughly 2 minutes to code...much less than the time it took to write this explanation! You now have data structures that are the logical representation of your view. You can add and remove sectors at will. You can change their position and size and it will be reflected in their rendering. You can unit test them and run your simulation without actually creating the views themselves. If you add handlers for GUI events then you can add breakpoints and see exactly what's going on. And throughout all this there isn't a single line of code-behind anywhere, you're not even having to use that custom "SectorView" control that you were creating in your original code.

Comment: I tried it without an explicit height, but the text was still way too big; I thought maybe the height would force it to shrink - perhaps something else behind the scenes was making it bigger? See, that's what I don't like about WPF - too much goes on behind the scenes where you can't debug or even figure out what's going on. If using code-behind is a "horrible misuse of WPF", maybe WPF just isn't the right tool for me. Care to recommend an alternative? I was using WinForms, but even the best GUIs I could come up with using that were ugly pieces of junk...

Comment: @ekolis nothing is happening "behind the scenes" in any way. You clearly defined a Viewbox which will apply a `RenderTransform` to your entire UI, hence the text resizes too. Remove the Viewbox and be happy, please.